# Post data in C# and use response in CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to post parameters to a website and use the response in my CefSharp browser. Using my current code it posts the data and loads the html in CefSharp. The html page that loads is exactly what I want meaning the post works but as soon as I click a button it just loads up the website without an of the parameters I posted. How could I use the cookies from the request so that if I click the button everything should remain the way it was posted.

Here is the code i'm using to post:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { },
        { },
        { },  <----- Parameters go here
        { },
        { },
    };

    //WebClient client2 = new WebClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("URL", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
    chrome.LoadHtml(responseString, "URL");
```

Comment: Search the source for LoadRequest, think that's the method name

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_LoadRequest.htm

Comment: I have the same problem . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810291/send-a-url-to-chromiumwebbrowser-with-posted-data.You mean with above code you can post the value to URL ?